# If Migration Assistant is interrupted, will it resume from where it left off?

Tags: macos, time-machine, time-capsule, migration-assistant

I stopped my MA and started it again and the new estimated spaces to transfer are different (I took a picture before the first attempt). Just want to make sure that’s what’s happening, and not that the backup is corrupted. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different, Herman. In the past, the data was cached and interrupting was a bit of a pain. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/19248/can-you-stop-the-migration-assistant-midway-through - mind editing in your version of macOS? That might help a newer answer be provided or someone try to reproduce. As long as it finishes, that would be a good sign you’re OK or the tool can clean things up better now.

Answer (score 1):

I stopped and resumed MA 3 times. Each time the estimated space was less than the previous time. It looks as if MA does indeed store partially transferred data somewhere and then puts it all together in the end, or something to that effect.